# What are my options for performance appraisals for software engineers?

Tags: productivity, performance-reviews, performance, bonus

We are a small software development company. We are currently working on having a proper performance appraisal system with incentive tied to performance however, no idea how to implement it effectively.

I would like to know like, how to effectively measure performance of software developer/ engineers / testers and how to implement the whole system that help business retain its talent with incentives and also motivate team!

How other companies are doing in this area?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about productivity and measuring performance.  That is a task specific to the management role and business processes, which makes this off topic here.

Comment: Obligatory link to Joel on Software: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000070.html

Comment: My answer to a similar question applies here I think: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/23990/105 In short: If the system can be abused, it will

Comment: @Chad I think the implications of the questions go beyond productivity and can clearly affect the workplace, so I think we're in topic here.

Comment: @lorenzog - Just because it pertains to the workplace does not make it on topic.  While management questions are on topic business policy questions are not.  This question really fails the [Good Subjective/Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) test in that there is no one right answer.

Comment: @Chad sorry for being picky, but in your first comment you said "management role and business processes are off topic here". In your last comment you said "management questions are on topic [but] business policy questions are not". Also, as this place is called "the workplace" I'd expect questions on the workplace to be in topic :) Nevertheless, your link does say that this is not a place to discuss, but rather to present facts and that holds partially true for this question. Perhaps a rephrasing of the initial question might make it more apt for this site?

Comment: @lorenzog - We always encourage that.  If you feel you can adjust the question to make it on topic please do.

Comment: @lorenzog - It is not that management role questions are off topic it is that this question is about a task that is specific to the management role with specific business processes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: you can't measure performance for engineering. No matter what metric you use, it won't fit all cases and this is more so the bigger your team becomes.

Long answer: it is a very gray area. First of all, money is [not a good motivator](http://www.forbes.com/2010/04/06/money-motivation-pay-leadership-managing-employees.html); if you want to motivate people, let them *master* a skill. Secondly, what works in a small software company will most likely not work with a bigger team. People will find tricks to game the system while PM will rely on "metrics" for a false sense of security rather than personal judgment and familiarity with individuals.

You can, however, add a system to make sure performance reviews are fair: **transparency**. Let the engineers chose their **own** goals for the next period (usually six months); have the manager agree on them. Make sure to throw in the mix a bit of **technical** and a bit of **human** side, e.g. "I will learn a new technology/language/library and give at least one tech talk on the topic to my fellow engineers". At the end of the period, **review** the goals, let the engineer **self-assess** his performance and the manager double check how they did. Be aware that engineers tend to under-estimate themselves. Be **fair**. Record everything in **written form**.

Then, if the majority of the goals are met, you can talk about raises. But ***do not*** base raises solely on this, otherwise you risk lots of anger if somebody's performance fails because of other team members.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1168131/204634) SO question, or [this](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2010-10-10/) Dilbert comic for the funny side of things. [Rands](http://randsinrepose.com/archives/no-surprises/) has, as always, some good insight on the topic (see also [this other](http://randsinrepose.com/archives/avoiding-the-fez/) post).

One word of advice: do not assume that an appraisal system is a way to save time. Properly done, a good appraisal system takes *more* time than not doing it.

UPDATE: see also [this](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/5290/1583) answer on the Project Management stackexchange site.

Comment: Thank you for posting a detailed answer with explanation. I agree with you and understand your points.. they are truly valid. I will go through the links you shared and try to come up with some simple system for appraisal system.

Comment: @Krunal no problem :) I hope I made your team's life a little bit easier!

Comment: @Krunal better to forget the entire idea prp systems will be abused - normally they get captured by HR and used to drive headcount reductions and/or reduce the pay quanta - with the result of destroying morale and losing you your best people.

Comment: @Pepone Thank you for your suggestion. I understand point you are trying to make. But there should be some system (if not metric) on which performance is measured, and it needs to be transparent and with human factor like lorenzog has advised.

Comment: I am not ashamed to say I will not show up for work tomorrow if I'm not going to get paid and if I'm able to support my claim, will always ask for more money. Imagine Forbes Magazine claiming money isn't important-what a joke.

Comment: @JeffO my point was that to improve performance, money is not important. It does not imply that money is not important at all. "If my grandma had wheels, she would be a bycicle" does not mean she is a bycicle.

Comment: @krunal sorry you must be either very young or naive If you think that there is a simple metric that you can some how magically use to make a PRP/APR system immune from all its negative effects.

Comment: @lorenzog unfortunately employees lie a lot about how they view pay/perks so saying pay has no effect is I am afraid wrong

Comment: @Pepone Yes, you're right. I am young as well as non-experienced with this area... so I'm learning and before we do it, I want to know best practices of the industry to understand how its done! Do you think there is something wrong in knowing how others are doing it?

Comment: @Pepone If you think your employees are lying to you then there is an issue with the trust level you have with your team. Its completely a different issue and before you thing something like this.. you need to overcome your belief and ensure the trusting environment within your business team.

Comment: @JeffO Money is important up to a threshold (can you pay your bills?  is it fair market value?).  Once you have passed that threshold, it's no longer very important when compared against other motivators such as work/life balance, job appreciation, good team chemistry, etc.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your insights and comments.. we actually did it like you suggested. We worked on system where we discuss and note down the yearly goals of each team and then based on goal, define the strategy and metrics to monitor the performance of the team over time. We monitor it on monthly basis. Similarly there is a KPI for each individual in team which is very specific to the work assigned to him which helps us monitor how they are performing. Moreover, we included other personal goals like learning new technology, or writing tech papers, etc. based on which performance is measured.